# Unable to retreive org to VSCode

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, visualstudiocode, retrieve

I am having problem with retrieving org to my VS Code. I usually work with IntelliJ, but I need to do some quick testing on my other laptop, so I tried using VS Code.

Here are steps that I did so far:

- I installed and updated CLI,
- also I installed SF extension pack on VS Code.

When I tun VS Code I do command:
`SFDX: Create project with manifest`

- then I tried both standard and empty
- I enter all the names
- `SFDX: Authorize an ORG`
- I get Successfully authorized...
- I then set that org as default (tried without this also)
- then right click on package.xml and retrieve,
- and I get Error:

> Metadata API request failed: Component conversion failed: FILE_ENDED

Also, I tried with this command: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml` but same thing.

I tried to delete everything and do it again, but same thing happens.

This is new issue for me because I used to connect to this org like 6-7 months ago, and it worked normally.

Version: sfdx-cli/7.169.1 node-v16.17.0

Comment: Check this link there are some workarounds you can try https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1262

Comment: Try to  uninstall Salesforce CLI and re-install it.

Comment: Ty all.
I tried both things, but nothing worked. The only thing that works is to pull one thing at the time. There is probably something with this project that VS Code does not like. I will stick to the IntelliJ and IL2